# Generated excel file size is very big with php and mysql export

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am using php and mysql to generate excel file. Every thing works fine. I am using html table code and exporting data to excel file. But the downloaded file is having bigger size for 20k records it is showing nearly 35 MB. Below is my code .

```
<?php 
$generated_date =  date("Y-m-d-H-i-s"); 
$filename = 'order_detail_report'.$generated_date;
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
?>
```

Html table code

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr>
    <th class="excel_style">Order Number</th>
    <th class="excel_style">EAN</th>
    <th class="excel_style">Article #</th>
    <th class="excel_style">Amazon Price</th>
    <th class="excel_style">ERP Price</th>
    <th class="excel_style">Requested Quantity</th>
    <th class="excel_style">Dispatch Quantity</th>
    <th class="excel_style">Rejected Quantity</th>
    <th class="excel_style">Cancelled Quantity</th>
  </tr>
```

While loop

```
<?php 
$query = "my select query";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqliConn,$query);
while($result= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
?>
<tr>
<td class="tdstyle"><?php echo $result['order_id'];?></td>
<td class="tdstyle"><?php echo $result['ean'];?></td>
<td class="tdstyle"><?php echo $result['article_no'];?></td>
<td class="tdstyle"><?php echo $result['net_price'];?></td>
<td class="tdstyle"><?php echo $result['erp_price'];?></td>
<td class="tdstyle"><?php echo $result['requested_quantity'];?></td>
<td class="tdstyle"><?php echo $result['dispatch_quantity']?></td>
<td class="tdstyle"><?php echo $result['rejected_quanity'];?></td>
<td class="tdstyle"><?php echo $result['cancelled_quantity']?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

How to solve this size of the file problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I use phpexcel library I am getting some out of memory exception. So client asked me don't use phpexcel library.

Comment: you can create php memory limit by (ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');) can you call it ?

Comment: yes, I tried even this was not worked .

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is exact problem - the size of result generated file or the memory getting exhausting?

But, lets assume that the problem is memory getting exhausting. Do you really need to generate excel(.xslx) files or CSV format is acceptable? You can generate CSV file with a really low memory usage like this

```
<?php 
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$query = "my select query";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqliConn,$query);
while($result= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $fields = [
        $result['order_id'],
        $result['ean'],
        $result['article_no'],
        $result['net_price'],
        $result['erp_price'],
        $result['requested_quantity'],
        $result['dispatch_quantity'],
        $result['rejected_quantity'],
        $result['cancelled_quantity']
    ]
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: But if xlsx format is requirement, you need to use cell caching to reduce memory consumption - see documentation https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md As PHPExcel is deprecated for a long time I would recomend to use its direct successor - https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/memory_saving/

Comment: The problem is size of the downloaded excel file. The file format should be excel only.

Comment: The big size is because HTML format you use to generate XLS file is quite verbose. Document with 20000 empty rows has size ~6.5Mb So, there are 2 options. First one - compress result file and send it in zip format. And second one - utilize PHPExcel/PhpSpreadsheet with properly configured cell cache.